# how to host sveltekit app in sharedhosting that supports node using adapter-node

Tags: cpanel, svelte, sveltekit

Help Needed to deploy svelte-kit app in shared hosting [ a2 hosting ] that supports nodejs via cpanel / ssh

**1st method i have tried**

i have tried copying whole project to my hosting and try deploy using cpanel "setup nodejs app" option

but it shoes vite have not present.

**2nd method i have tried**

i have tried the steps guided by official sveltekit [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node) but i dont know what am i doing wrong.

did i need to change any port in my index.js

```
const path = env('SOCKET_PATH', false);
const host = env('HOST', '0.0.0.0');
const port = env('PORT', !path && '3000');
```

the above code is the default code after build `npm run build`.

error logs after running my app in my hsoting the method recommened by official docs.

```
file:///home/dynami44/test.dynamicsites.net/index.js:1
var http = require('http');
           ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/dynami44/test.dynamicsites.net/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/dynami44/test.dynamicsites.net/index.js:1:12
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:527:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

Node.js v18.9.1
```

some one have experience in it , please guide me..

Comment: You don't need to provide any environment variable if it is not necessary. By default, it will listen on `0.0.0.0:3000`. Only provide variables if this is not what you expect. Please, could you detail your deployment process? You point to the official documentation but, since it is not working, there must be something clearly off on your process.

Comment: @carlosV2 i followed the steps but got these error while trying to run ```Node.js v18.9.1
file:///home/dynami44/test.dynamicsites.net/shims.js:8152
  return await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, {
                           ^

RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
    at lazyllhttp (file:///home/dynami44/test.dynamicsites.net/shims.js:8152:28) ```   iam also following this node app setup guide https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts

Comment: You are showing now a different error than the one you showed before plus you haven't detailed the steps you take to deploy. You just point at instructions in pages but it is clearly not working for you so there must be something different that you have or do. Please, detail your steps. In addition to this, the error you are showing now seems to be related with WASM which it isn't even mention on any of the pages you sent.